# Странное поведение EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Есть `EditText`, который странно себя ведет, при печати символы в нем добавляются не слево направо, а с права на лево (как-будто набор текста идет на арабском). Я нигде не выставляла, что печать символов должна быть с права на лево, в чем может быть проблема?

Код xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWorkItemNumber"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/doc_title_font_size" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvClaimWorkName"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvWorkItemNumber"
        android:textSize="@dimen/doc_title_font_size"
        android:text="test type 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvClaimPlan"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvClaimWorkName"
        android:textSize="@dimen/doc_title_font_size"
        android:text="2"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etClaimFact"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvClaimPlan"
        android:textSize="@dimen/doc_title_font_size"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Скриншот, я набираю "1234567", а получаю "7654321":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код TextWatcher:

```
    etComment = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etComment);
    etComment.setText(docWorkComment);
    etComment.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = DBH.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(DBH.DocK.DC.NOTE, String.valueOf(s));
            db.update(DBH.DocK.TABLE_NAME, cv, "tabID=" + 1 + " and file_id=" + "'" + docId + "'", null);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: а можете скриншот показать?

Comment: `android:textDirection="anyRtl"` попробуйте с этим поэксперементировать

Comment: @metalurgus Добавила скриншот

Comment: @Asgard  добавила, но не помогло

Comment: @Lucky_girl,  может в стилях что-то? Или это InstantRun опять глючит...

Comment: а в коде у вас для него нет TextWatcher'а?

Comment: @metalurgus Есть TextWatcher

Comment: @metalurgus А TextWatcher как-то влияет на набор текста?

Comment: тогда показывайте код. Возможно, из за него и работает так

Answer (score 3):

Вы жестко выставили ширину `android:layout_width="200dp"` и ваш `EditText` уехал за пределы экрана справа. При этом у Вас выставлено `android:gravity="center"`, т.е. текст набирается по центру, поэтому получается такой эффект.

Удалите `android:gravity="center"` или разберитесь с размерами по ширине.

Comment: я поставила gravity left, и эффект тот же самый.

Comment: Убрала gravity полностью, но текст набирается так же.

Comment: @Lucky_girl  Уберите `gravity` и попробуйте, к примеру, выставить `android:layout_width="50dp"`. Посмотрите, что будет. Думаю, что проблема с разметкой компонентов по ширине.